# Long title in mobile view breaks style

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

I’ve found a small, yet annoying, CSS-error in the mobile view of Stack Exchange. It seems like long titles breaks the style, which causes the up-vote arrow and the answer button to break the row and fall beneath the intended spot. From the looks of it, the title cell, or the tags, increase too much and causes this minor CSS-error.

[image]

Is it possible to fix this?